# Synchrotron emissivity change of variables

Tags: radiation, dirac-delta-distributions

I have an expression for an emissivity $j_\nu$

$$j_\nu =a_0 \left(\frac{p}{mc}\right)^2 B^2\; \delta\mathopen{}\left(\nu -a_1 \left(\frac{p}{mc}\right)^2B\right)$$

where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are arbitrary constants with units $\rm W \: Hz^{-1}\:T^{-2}$ and $\rm Hz\:  T^{-1}$ respectively. $B$ is a magnetic field in $\rm T$, $p$ is momentum, $m$ is mass, $c$ is light speed, and $\nu$ is frequency all with their regular units.

How would you express $j_\nu$ as a delta function not of $\nu$ but one in $p$?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436782/2451

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function):

> $$\delta\big(f(x)\big) = \sum_{i}\frac{\delta(x-a_{i})}{\left|{\frac{df}{dx}(a_{i})}\right|},$$
>   where $a_{i}$ are the roots of the function $f(x)$.

In your case, simply set $f(p) = \nu - \frac{a_1B}{m^2c^2} p^2$.